# Releasing StreamReader File for a sec

Tags: c#, streamreader

i have a streamReader which i use to keep watching a file for any new lines added, 
it goes like this :

```
while (true)
{
  try
  {
    line = sr.ReadLine();
    if (line == null)
    {
      break;
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
    {
      //Do Stuff
    }
    Thread.Sleep(2);
  }
}
```

now i want to release the file for a while every now and then ,

i can close sr for a sec or two and then reintilize it and use it again but i was wondering if there is a proper way for doing that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to track changes to the file and only then open the file to check for the new lines.

You can use the last `seek` position to start the new seek from, so the whole file doesn't need to be re-read.

Comment: using a lastSeenLineNumber will make it horribly slow; you cannot 'random access' seek to a linenumber, necessitating a full file re-read; this will be dog slow (for the surplus reads) as well as have a potential for heap fragmentation, especially with varying line lengths in the input

Answer (score 0):

> proper way for doing that?

Reopening, Seek() to the old position and continue work should be your best option. If you want other parties to be able to continue accessing the file, just specify proper [flags for FileShare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh.aspx) e.g. FileShare.ReadWrite

Perhaps look at memory mapped files for .NET 4.0

Comment: i already do that , i figured the problem was that i forgot to close the sr after every update of the file..